# Data is not committed to DB in spring transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, struts2

My application is spring,struts2 and hibernateand database is postgress 9.2. Problem is DAO method not commiting data with out using flush.

My spring.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee     http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">




<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="depo" jndi-name="java:/depo"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="depo"/>


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!--    <prop     key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <!--    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>

            <value>model.AtOrganisation</value>

        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"   class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<bean id="orgdao" class="dao.OrganisationDaoImp">
    <property name="sessionfactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="empAction" class="action.OraganisationAction">
    <property name="orgdao" ref="orgdao" />
</bean>
```

And my DAO class is :

```
 @Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void addOrg(AtOrganisation org) {

    Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();

    session.saveOrUpdate(org);
    //session.flush();


}
```

Can any one point out what did I miss here.
Note: If I uncomment flush() data will commit.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: data is not inserting to db.
i need to do it with out calling flush()

Comment: Why do you think to flush a session when a transaction is open?

Comment: Yeah I don't want to use flush. That's why I need help from you to remove flush.When I comment flush data is not committing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to retrieve the same session that Spring is using by calling:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

The call to `openSession()` will create an entirely new session that is not being managed by Spring, as opposed to the call to `getCurrentSession()`, that retrieves the same session managed by the `@Transactional` mechanism.

Comment: I have tried this. But its says there's no currently open session.
Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
          session.saveOrUpdate(org);

Comment: OK.Its works after change spring.xml to
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

instead of
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

Answer (score -1):

First of all annotate method with the @Transactional annotation on the service level and leave  DAO without Transactional annotation. Then let's see how it's working.

Comment: I didnt use service layer.
are you sure if I add service layer solve problem?

Comment: Of course I am not sure at the moment, but I think so. That's why I wrote let's see how it works.